# Can't get image file through image picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i can't get images file through image picker in flutter.

```
void _getImage() async {
    print("getImage");
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? image = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(image);
}
```

and error's occur, look at this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3ja8.png)

my enviroment is M1 pro, ios15.2

Comment: Try using an emulator with ios 13.

Comment: Did you try running on real device?

Comment: No i don't. I will try it

Comment: did you add the permissions in the info.plist ?

Comment: Sure, I fixed this issue but it's not stable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_getImage(BuildContext context) async {
    var picture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      imageFile = File(picture!.path);
      dirPath = picture.path;
      print('path');
      print(dirPath);
    });
  }
```